# What to do when a code review tool declares unmatched types?

Tags: python-3.x, casting

I am working on developing a large-scale Python (backend) project.  I was working with a firm that does extensive testing, and they built the frontend and test tools.  Before every deploy, all the tools (like linters) are run regularly.

I had put down the code for a while, and now it fails many tests.  Some of these are deprecation warnings for features or syntax soon to be deprecated, and they note they started classifying those as warnings (to later become errors) starting January 1, 2020, so I know they make dynamic changes in the tools themselves.

My problem is a bunch of code that used to pass no longer does.  And the error is always the same: if I have a line that looks like so, I get an error that says something along the lines of "error: may not use operator '-' with incompatible types; a and b are of types numpy.array and NoneType":

```
x = a - b
```

This gets fixed by making the code super-messy with this sort of fix:

```
x = a.astype(float) - b.astype(float)
```

It's even worse because in the actual code there are 3 variables, all doing addition and subtraction with a 'c' that is an integer array kicking around along with the two numpy arrays.  But then the code goes from:

```
x = a - b - c
```

to:

```
x = a.astype(float) - b.astype(float) - c.astype(float)
```

And this won't work since int's don't have an astype method.  The error looks like this now:

File "/home/engine.py", line 165, in Foo
    lower_array[t].astype(float)) / num_values.astype(float) 
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'astype'

Thus, I end up with:

```
x = a.astype(float) - b.astype(float) - float(c)
```

This is all extraordinarily cumbersome and nasty casting that is required, and makes the code impossible to read.

The odd thing to me is that all three arrays were instantiated as numpy arrays, i.e.,:

```
a=numpy.array(_a)
b=numpy.array(_b)
c=numpy.array(_c)
```

When I ask the code to put output to stdout the type of all three vars, they all say .  Yet, the next line of code blows up and dumps, saying "Attribute error: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'astype'"

I can't fathom how a static code analyzer determines the types - other than as numpy.ndarray type - since Python uses duck-typing.  Thus, the type could change dynamically.  But that's not the case here; all three vars are identified as numpy.ndarray type, but "z = a - b - c" fails.

Anyone understand what's going on here?

Comment: I believe that `x = a.astype(float) - b.astype(float) - c` should work and `return` a `float`; is that correct?

Comment: Yes, it all works without all the silliness.  It's the static test that calls out errors and gives stack traces.  I am not expert in this, but I think what is happening is like this: (1) static analysis is done; (2) a dynamic test is run which loads up dummy vars and calls the code leading to these errors.  I suspect that since the log captures a stack trace that there is a dynamic run.  So, the core works unmodified, but gives a stack trace either from the static analysis or from running the code from a fixture, etc.

Comment: From the error `"error: may not use operator '-' with incompatible types; a and b are of types numpy.array and Null"` it appears that yes, it's using dummy vars, and it fails at `b=None`; if so, it surprises me that works for `b.astype(float)` perhaps a check if the values (or one value) are different than `None` might do the trick. Also, `x = a.astype(float) - b.astype(float) - c` should work flawlessly (testing) because of the implicit casting that Python's doing.

Comment: yes, I agree that division should work.  I just tried to get ahead of new errors being reported.  But 'x = a.astype(float) - b.astype(float) - c' works fine.

Answer (score 0):

After much work, the answer is to ignore the linter.  Readable code is the object, not code that satisfies a linter.